# Regular expression End of that line

Tags: regex

First the example:

```
The car is blue
The house is yellow
Fish swim
The fire truck is red
This text should look like this after applying the regex.
The car is blue.
The house is yellow.
Fish swim
The fire truck is red.
```

So I want to replace all sentences beginning with "the" with a dot.
How can I do that? Been sitting on it for hours.
Best regards

Comment: I use a find and replace tool. 
I can search there with regex and then change the searched sections.
For example, I look for commas and can replace them with a dot.

Answer (score 0):

Regex is used for pattern matching, not for updating the string.

To search lines starting with "the" you can write regex pattern like this:

`^the` --- this matches "the" string which is at the beginning of the line.

You can find out the last character of a string using any of the language. For Ex: in javaScript: str.slice(-1) where str is your string.

Comment: Okay, that's right. But can I get the last sign of those lines?

Comment: ^the is used to find the string which is starting with "the".

Comment: Okey. And how can I find out the last character of the found line? :)

Comment: ^the.*
this gives you the line which is starting with "the". Then you can find out the last character of a string using any of the language. For Ex: in javaScript: str.slice(-1) where str is your string.